# Should one apply salt/antifreeze on the road right before it snows?

Tags: snow

Or should one apply the salt/antifreeze after shoveling up the snow?

Comment: What's the predicted temperature?  How much snow is predicted to fall?

Comment: Am thinking of a variety of conditions, but I'm thinking for maybe 6-8 inches of predicted snowfall at a temperature of slightly below freezing (recent Boston snowfalls)

Answer (score 2):

Well if you apply it before you will just be shoveling it away.

If you apply it after it will only help for the next batch of snow.  But it will also tear up your road.

I opt for nothing and dealing with the snow.

Comment: Seconded. Salt if you need to break up ice.

Comment: If you apply it after, could it prevent ice from forming?

Comment: @InquilineKea - Of course.  To what extent depends on how much you put down, temperature, and moisture.  There are a lot of things that would keep ice from forming.  Salt is usually the easiest to throw down for most people.  It totally tears up roads though.